# How to know when device is set to always discoverable?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want my device to be discoverable always. So I

> set the EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION extra's value **to 0**

as the [docs describe](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#DiscoverDevices).

My issue arises when I have to check the `resultCode` in `onActivityResult()`.

> If the user **responds "Yes,"** then the device becomes discoverable for
>   the specified amount of time. Your activity then receives a call to
>   the onActivityResult() callback, with the **result code equal to the
>   duration** that the device is discoverable. If the user **responded "No"**,
>   or if an error occurred, the **result code is RESULT_CANCELED**.

**Problem**

- Result code when the device is set to be always discoverable is zero.
- RESULT_CANCELED constant is zero.

In code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == DISCOVERABILITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            // Compilation error because the two constants have the same value
            switch (resultCode){
                case ALWAYS_DISCOVERABLE: // zero
                    doSomethingWhenRespondedIsYes();
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED: // zero
                    doSomethingWhenRespondIsNo();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How am I going to know when the user responded with Yes (device to be always discoverable) or No?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this to begin with.  If a device is always discoverable, anyone can pair with it.  That's fairly insecure.  It looks like this is a hole in the API, as they really don't want always discoverable to be used.  You may want to instead make it discoverable for an hour at a time, with a timer to re-prompt the user.

Comment: I am familiar about the security issue but I want the device to be always discoverable. If indeed there is a hole in the API then there is nothing I can do about it.